# GA4 Admin API for data retention method via Google App Script not working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-4

I am unable to pull data retention settings from GA4 Admin API via Google App Script. I am using the below code. I am using this [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZWUt.png).

```
function getDataRetention() {
 var data = AnalyticsAdmin.Properties.getDataRetentionSettings({name:'properties/XXXXXX/dataRetentionSettings'});
 
 Logger.log(data);
}
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

I used the API explorer tool provided by Google to test out API Calls. I am getting a 200 status response which means the configuration is correct, but something seems to be wrong in the above code:

[image: API Explorer Tool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the arguments of the method of `AnalyticsAdmin.Properties.getDataRetentionSettings`, it seems `getDataRetentionSettings(name: string)`. So, how about the following modification? In order to confirm the arguments of Google APIs of Advanced Google Services, this report might be useful. [Ref (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/taking-advantage-of-auto-completion-of-script-editor-for-google-apps-script-be088a76cd86)

#### From:

```
var data = AnalyticsAdmin.Properties.getDataRetentionSettings({name:'properties/XXXXXX/dataRetentionSettings'});
```

#### To:

```
var data = AnalyticsAdmin.Properties.getDataRetentionSettings('properties/XXXXXX/dataRetentionSettings');
```

#### References:

- [Method: properties.getDataRetentionSettings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/getDataRetentionSettings)
- [Taking Advantage of Auto-completion of Script Editor for Google Apps Script](https://medium.com/google-cloud/taking-advantage-of-auto-completion-of-script-editor-for-google-apps-script-be088a76cd86)

Comment: Auto Completion is really helpful.. Thanks for sharing

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.